# Rails server error after updating Ruby (Name Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I updated Ruby to 2.2.2 from 2.0.0 because I think it may have been causing issues with Heroku, but now when I try and start the rails server I'm getting a name error, and because I'm new to RoR I have no idea what's causing it.

Here is my log:

```
C:\row\dev\my_app>rails s
C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.
rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveM
odelHelper (NameError)
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_
view/view_paths.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstrac
t_controller/rendering.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_
controller/base.rb:204:in `<class:Base>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_
controller/base.rb:164:in `<module:ActionController>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_
controller/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/respond
ers/controller_method.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/respond
ers.rb:15:in `<module:Responders>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/respond
ers.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise.rb:7
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler.r
b:134:in `require'
        from C:/row/dev/david_youtube/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required
)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be that I had two versions of Ruby installed. After removing all versions of Ruby, and doing a clean install of 2.2.2 I was able to start the Rails server.